# Keep model validation working with has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

So I have this model named `Post` and it `has_many :comments`. Each comment has a `title` field.

The `Comment` model has this structure:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  validates :title, presence: true
end
```

And this is my `Post` model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

So in my `Posts` ***controller*** I add the comments for the certain post like this:

```
@post.comments.create(title: params[:title])
```

But even if `params[:title]` is blank, no error will be shown, even though there is a `validates` call on the model.

Why would this be happening? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `create` method doesn't raise an error but instead returns `nil` when it fails. Call `create!` instead to raise an error when the method fails. Same thing with `update` and `update!`.

Edit:
 To get the `comments` errors, change your code to something like:

```
@comment = @post.comments.build(title: params[:title])
if @comment.save
  redirect_to comment_path(@comment) #or wherever you want to go
else
  render 'new'
end
```

The `@post.errors` returns the errors for the post itself. IIRC, it would say something like `comments is invalid`. But to actually get the errors you would have to call `@comment.errors`.

Comment: `create` returns the unsaved object if it fails.

Comment: Okay this definitely blocks when the validation fails. But instead of raising an exception, can we make it so that it only populates the `@post.error` hash, like other normal errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this instead:

```
@comment = @post.comments.build(title: params[:title])
@comment.save
```

and if the comment validation fails, it will return false